# Solve for $\lambda(x): \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ given two cases.

Tags: functions

> Solve for $\lambda:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ in $\lambda(x)=\begin{cases}
> x+1 & x\in2\Bbb N \\
> 2\lambda(\lfloor x/2\rfloor) & x\in2\Bbb N+1
> \end{cases}$

I know that an answer is $\lambda(x)=x+1$, but is it the only one?

We know it is true for $x\in2\Bbb N$, but what about $x\in 2\Bbb N+1$?

Let $x=2k+1$ for some $k\in \Bbb N$.

Then $\lambda(2k+1)=2\lambda(\lfloor (2k+1)/2\rfloor)=2\lambda(\lfloor k+1/2\rfloor)=2\lambda(k)$

But now we are in the same scenario, having to check the parity of $k$ to be able to progress.

Is there a way to prove this, maybe inductively? Thanks.

Comment: Best not to format "cases" in a title.

Comment: Garmekain ^^^^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Does the base-2 expansion of the input $x$ tell you anything?

**Solution**:
The base-2 expansion of the input $x$ has $m$ trailing 1s: $$x \equiv ( d_1 \ldots d_n 0 \underbrace{1 \cdots 1}_m )_2.$$ Note that $x$ is even if and only if $m = 0$. If $m \geq 1$, the operation $\lfloor x / 2 \rfloor$ is equivalent to removing the last trailing 1 from the above expansion. Therefore, \begin{multline*}\lambda(x) = 2^m \lambda( (d_1 \ldots d_n 0)_2 ) = 2^m \left[(d_1 \ldots d_n 0)_2 + 1 \right] \\ = 2^m (d_1 \ldots d_n 1)_2 = (d_1 \ldots d_n 1 \underbrace{0 \cdots 0}_m)_2 = x + 1.\end{multline*}

Comment: Exactly. But how can it be proved that $x+1$ is the only solution for $\lambda$?

Comment: Try looking at the base-2 expansion of $23$, $\lfloor 23 / 2 \rfloor = 11$, $\lfloor 11 / 2 \rfloor = 5$, and $\lfloor 5 / 2 \rfloor = 2$. You should be able to spot a pattern that you can generalize from.

Comment: Does the fact that "eventually it will reach an even number, because no binary expansion of all 1s exist" do the work? I feel it lacks something, hence the question.

Comment: It will eventually reach an even number simply because $\lfloor 1 / 2 \rfloor = 0$ and $0$ is even.